# Selecting images from file explorer to add them in PyCharm directory

Tags: python

When I do image processing in pycharm, I can't add images from my file explorer in the directory. How should I fix it?

I've done what I can as possible but I'm a starter of python. I wasn't able to solve this. So, I know this's not enough by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using pycharm you must have created a project folder in a directory
That directory is located at C:\Users<user>\PycharmProjects if you have done default installation this will be visible in file explorer and you could use normal copy paste then